# How to test private method of a private static class

Tags: java, junit

How can i unit test a private method, which is in a private static class.

```
 public class ProjectModel {
          //some code
        private static class MyStaticClass{
            private model (Object obj, Map<String , Object> model)
          }
}
```

I tried to realise that its give NoSuchMethodException

```
Method method = projectModel.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("model", methodParameters);
```

Comment: First you should ask yourself: do I really need to write unit tests for private methods? If you do want to test them, you shouldn't test them directly, but through the public methods that use them.

Comment: Two things: 1: this won't compile, as `model()` does not have a return type. 2: private methods don't need testing. Instead you should make sure that the non-private methods this one is used by return correct results.

Comment: You're getting a declared method from the outer class.

Comment: it's a valid question. no reason for a downvote...

Comment: @Mena No the its called form a method inside the static class , and the method which is calling it is public, but i need to test the private method part.

Comment: @RishiKeshPathak again, `projectModel.getClass().getDeclaredMethod` gets a method of `ProjectModel`, unless you named your instance `projectModel` but it's an instance of `MyStaticClass`.

Comment: IMO Testing the methods that use this private static class should be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your class `ProjectModel` is in package `privateaccessor.tst` and your non-static method `model` returns an `int`.

```
package privateaccessor.tst;
public class ProjectModel {
  //some code
  private static class MyStaticClass{
    private int model (Object obj, Map<String , Object> model) {
      return 42;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your test you can use reflection to get the private class' `Class` object and create an instance. Then you can use the `PrivateAccessor` (contained in [Junit Addons](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/util/PrivateAccessor.html)) to call method `model()`.

```
@Test
public void testPrivate() throws Throwable {
  final Class clazz = Class.forName("privateaccessor.tst.ProjectModel$MyStaticClass");
  // Get the private constructor ...
  final Constructor constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
  // ... and make it accessible.
  constructor.setAccessible(true);
  // Then create an instance of class MyStaticClass.
  final Object instance = constructor.newInstance();
  // Invoke method model(). The primitive int return value will be
  // wrapped in an Integer.
  final Integer result = (Integer) PrivateAccessor.invoke(instance, "model", new Class[]{Object.class, Map.class}, new Object[]{null, null});
  assertEquals(42, result.intValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to resolve the exception :

```
Method method = projectModel.getClass().getDeclaredClasses()[0]
    .getDeclaredMethod("model", methodParameters);
```

For testing purpose, you can try below code to invoke `model` method:

```
Class<?> innerClass = projectModel.getClass().getDeclaredClasses()[0];

Constructor<?> constructor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
constructor.setAccessible(true);

Object mystaticClass = constructor.newInstance();
Method method = mystaticClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("model", new Class[]{Object.class,Map.class});

method.setAccessible(true);  
method.invoke(mystaticClass, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general testing of the private methods and classes is not recommended. If you still want to test some non-public functionality, I'd suggest to make such methods and classes not `private`, but `package private` and place your test cases in the same package (but into separate source directory like it's usually done in maven projects).

Your particular reflection issue can be solved using

```
Class.forName(ProjectModel.class.getName()+"$MyStaticClass")
    .getDeclaredMethod("model", methodParameters);
```

But I would not recommend using such approach as it will be hard to support such test cases in future.